# log-log vs. normal plotting for showing linear dependency

Tags: regression, logarithm, linear

I have a set of data, basically measuring the running time of an algorithm against some gathered input. This is the summary of data:

```
  size           time       
Min.   :      0   Min.   :1.360e+04 
1st Qu.:   1006   1st Qu.:7.357e+05 
Median :   2410   Median :2.167e+06 
Mean   :  10565   Mean   :1.127e+07 
3rd Qu.:   7113   3rd Qu.:7.030e+06 
Max.   :1369374   Max.   :1.503e+09
```

When I plot the data, I observe a linear dependency and this is the result of lm(time~size):

```
Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-716682545   -1431468   -1129352    -521418 1228545549 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.043e+06  3.673e+05   2.839  0.00454 ** 
newdata$size 9.680e+02  9.013e+00 107.394  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 27100000 on 5835 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.664, Adjusted R-squared:  0.664 
F-statistic: 1.153e+04 on 1 and 5835 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

This is the output of lm((log(time) ~ log(size)):

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9079 -0.1558  0.1037  0.2855  3.7981 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       5.801648   0.035039   165.6   <2e-16 ***
log(newdata$size) 1.113745   0.004323   257.6   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 0.4673 on 5835 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9192,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9192 
F-statistic: 6.638e+04 on 1 and 5835 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Is log-log or normal scatter plot a better way to show this linear dependency?
Here are the images:

- Normal
  [image: normal]
- log-log
  [image: log-log]

Comment: Could you post your plots here? That might help. Note that the coefficient of your log-log analysis is close to 1, suggesting close to proportionality (beyond the intercept) between your 2 variables. Technical issue is which presentation will minimize some relevant measure of residual error.

Comment: A graph that is linear on a log-log plot is not exponential: it's a power relationship.  (Linear graphs on *log-linear* plots are exponential.)  You are, in effect, asking why a power law with a power around $1.113\ldots \approx 1$ might look approximately linear. It is difficult to provide a specific answer because your regressions appear to involve completely different data: what are `terminal_nodes` (in the first regression) and how are they related to `size` (in the summary data and second regression)?

Comment: Perhaps it's notation (being a physicist here) but wouldn't a linear slope on a log-log plot mean $y\sim x^n$ (power-law) and not exponential?

Comment: @whuber sorry, it was a mistake, I've updated the post

Comment: @EdM I added the plots

Comment: Wickoo, your post still says "*However, if I use a log-log plot, then it again looks linear, suggesting that the data is exponential.*", which as whuber pointed out is not correct

Comment: @Glen_b, yes, I realized that. I guess the data suggests that the relationship is linear, which is actually what I wanted. I didn't know how to interpret a log-log graph.

Comment: If the log-log plot is linear it suggests a power relationship, as whuber stated earlier. When you said "I update the post" I kind of expected you meant that you had addressed that in your post.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for reminding me. I corrected another point, but forgot to update my assumption which was wrong. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From these plots you almost certainly should be working on the log-log scale. It's best if the error is independent of the value of the variables, and by eye that is much more the case for the log-log plot than for the linear plot. Note for example how the big outlier in the upper left of the linear plot becomes much closer to the cloud of points in the log-log plot.  Furthermore, the points fill the display much better in the log-log plot. As noted in the comments to the question, a power of 1.11 is pretty close to linear.

Comment: Thanks! for drawing a regression line should I use `lm` in R or `lsfit`? I also saw somewhere someone using LOWESS? how about that?

Comment: Before you consider your work done you should examine the distribution of residuals and determine whether the log-log fit is good enough for your purposes. If you want a standard single regression line you do not want LOWESS, which is a combination of several locally weighted fits. In R you can use the `abline` command with the coefficients from`lm` to add a line to the plot.

Comment: thanks. Sorry if it sounds stupid, but how to know which distribution of residuals is good? And i don't remove outliers, is it necessary?

Comment: By eye it looks like there is a cloud of cases having x values between 200 and 2000 (2 x 10^2 to 2 x 10^3) that might end up substantially below your log-log linear regression line. You might want to pay attention to those points, depending on the purposes of your analysis.

Comment: Don't remove outliers unless you know they were erroneous data. Read the documentation for `plot.lm` for ways to display residuals and evaluate their relations to predicted values, the influence of individual observations, etc. You would like residuals (here, on the log scale) to be independent of the predicted value and evenly distributed above and below 0; ideally, some would argue they should have a normal distribution. Consider this an opportunity to learn about regression diagnostics.